# Role of RTS and DTR With CH340X, STM32WLE5, STM32CubeProgrammer

Tags: stm32, usb, uart, reset, bootloader

I am trying to (design a PCB where I will) program a STM32WLE5C8U6 via UART from my laptop using a CH340X in between. The CH340X shows this application circuit in the datasheet:
[image]

I understand what the RTS and DTR pins do, but I don't understand how / when they are triggered. The STM32CubeProgrammer software mentions them, but doesn't explain how exactly it is able to control the CH340X's RTS and DTR pins.

[image]

I would also like to have serial USB communication with my actual program after I flash it (this is more important than being able to program over USB/UART), and I was wondering if connecting the DTR / RTS pins will automatically make my program restart every time I connect my board to a computer. Is it worth connecting the RTS and DTR pins from the CH340X to the STM32? Or, will it lead to unpredictable behavior, meaning I should just expose the NRST and BOOT0 pins and enter the bootloader by physically moving jumpers/wires?

Comment: I have been looking into it as well, and from my understanding it should work if you chain the --rts and --dtr arguments when calling the STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe command line program that comes with STM32CubeProgrammer as described by this post: https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus-embedded-software/flash-loader-demonstrator-v2-1-0-rts-dtr-control-issue/m-p/522201/highlight/true#M39405